# Set Info.plist Yes or No Programmably

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, plist

Hi StackOverflow Developers, I have an question how can i set my `Info.plist` programmable Yes or No. So my app supports Backgroung Locaton Update. But as all iOS Devlopers know it kills the battery like nuts. So I want to detect if the iphone is plugged in then only support Background Porcessing and ifs not plugged in we could user [locationmanger startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: What do you mean "disable maps"? Do you want to stop getting location updates?

Comment: @sosborn I have changed my Question :)

Comment: Please don't change your question after it has been answered, now the answer that you've received doesn't match, and it becomes less of a resource.

Comment: If you are prevented from asking new questions by the system, please do not completely change your old questions in order to bypass this. This is considered to be defacing content here.

Comment: I am soory Brad Larson and Abizen I had to ask this question :)

Answer (score 7):

### Answer to original question

OP asked how to stop updating the location and the answer was

`CLLocationManager` has a `stopUpdatingLocation:` method.

### Answer to new question

From my understanding, the property list serves as a declaration of your intention to use location services in the background and is read-only in terms of its accessibility during run time. Therefore, it seems like the proper approach is to control `CLLocationManager` through its methods like `stopUpdatingLocation:` and  `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges:`.

You can control `CLLocationManager` based on the battery state with battery monitoring by registering for battery notifications using

```
[ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES ];
[ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self selector:@selector(
      reactToBatteryStatus) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil ];
```

With this you can determine if the phone is plugged in or not. However, you should only register for battery notifications, according to Apple guidelines, when you need to. So to unregister you use

```
[ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:NO ];
[ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] removeObserver:self name:
  UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil ];
```

Then based on the battery state you can do what you need.

```
+ (void) reactToBatteryStatus {
    UIDeviceBatteryState batteryState = [ UIDevice currentDevice ].batteryState;
    if ( batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging || batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull )
    {
        // Device is plugged in.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed my question.

Comment: Do you get my Question (I am soory for changing the question I was banned from asking Questions so I had to edit this one). Happy Holidays :)

Comment: Thanks for detecting Battery Changes but how can we change Info.plist for Background Location to Yes or No :)

Comment: Is it possible to change an Info.plist to Yes/NO.

Comment: Is their an alternative to start Background Location updating without the Info.plist.

Comment: I have an idea where we have two Info.plist one that has Yes for Background location and the other with NO. In then we could set them if the iPhone is plugged in. Is that even possible (I am a new Developer) :)

Comment: Instead of using the plist, I suggested controlling your location manager based on the battery state. So you can set the plist for background location updates so that it conforms to Apple guidelines, but in your app, you can turn on/off location updating programmatically.

Comment: So if I use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges: it will override the Location Background Processing to save Battery Life :)

Comment: Their is a button called "Start Directions" then should I start registering for battery notifications then if the user clicks the "Stop Directions" I unregistered the battery notifications. :)

Comment: I think you can figure it out from here. I'm going to stop adding comments because I'm getting the warning to avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: Didn't work is it gives me error "locationmanger is undefined" BUT I DID @property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

Comment: Could you help we with my Error :)

Comment: The [policy for comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) suggests not answering questions in comments. However, I can suggest using `NSLog(@"locationManager = %@", locationManager);` to help debug your problem.

Comment: locationManager = <CLLocationManager: 0xacc48b0> I am getting this in NSLog

Comment: I suggest you refer to the code in the [Locations sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Locations/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple and compare how you are initializing the location manager.